# Prevent default mouse scroll conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am scrolling section to section, but if I am on the last section (blue in the fiddle) and I scroll down, I want to scroll normally (blue is the last section and whatever is below should be scrolled normlly).

During scrolling among the sections I want it to scroll smoothly (as in not shake when scrolling harshly) so I use:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

However I need to disable that if scrolling down after the last section.

I have tried to to that by implementing a variable called `shake` which kind of works, BUT:

1) If I am on the one before last section (green), and I scroll down harshly, I get the shakes.

2) Once I've scrolled to the blue section after green, I cant scroll back up to green immediately, there is a few seconds delay before it will let me.

3) Once I've scrolled PAST the blue section and am scrolling normally, and then I scrolll up harshly, I get the shakes.

fiddle 1 - without the `shake` variable - https://jsfiddle.net/b67uw0cx/

fiddle 2 - with the `shake` variable - https://jsfiddle.net/axgzqj8h/1/

```
.div {
    width: 100%;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.abovefooter {
    background: gray;
    height: 200px;
}

.footer {
    background: black;
    height: 350px;
}


<div id="id0" data-id="0" class="nbhd red scrolledto"></div>
<div id="id1" data-id="1" class="nbhd yellow"></div>
<div id="id2" data-id="2" class="nbhd green"></div>
<div id="id3" data-id="3" class="nbhd blue"></div>
<div class="abovefooter"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>

var isAnimated = false;
var nbhdLength = $('.nbhd').length;
var lastSectionId = nbhdLength - 1;
var allHeight = ( nbhdLength - 1 ) * window.innerHeight;
var up = true;
var shake = true;

function setHeights() {
    $('.nbhd').css('height', window.innerHeight);
}

setHeights();

$('html').mousewheel(function(e) {

    if (shake) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    var up = e.deltaY > 0;

    if (up) {
        console.log('up');
        up = true;

    } else {
        console.log('down');
        up = false;
        // console.log(up);
    }


    if ( ! up && $('#id'+lastSectionId).hasClass('scrolledto') || ( ! up && ! $('.scrolledto').length ) ) {
        $('.scrolledto').removeClass('scrolledto');
        shake = false;
        return;
    }

    if (isAnimated) return;
    isAnimated = true;

    var currentSectionId = $('.nbhd.scrolledto').data('id');

    up ? currentSectionId-- : currentSectionId++;

    if (currentSectionId < 0) currentSectionId = 0;

    if ( ! $('.scrolledto').length ) currentSectionId = lastSectionId;

    $('.scrolledto').removeClass('scrolledto');

    var section = $('#id'+currentSectionId);

    section.addClass('scrolledto');

    var pos = section.offset().top;

    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000, function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
          isAnimated = false;
        },100);
        shake = true;
    });

});
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce any `shakes`, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. You are talking about the second fiddle? When on green scroll down harshly either with a mouse or a touchpad. If you can reproduce shakes in the first fiddle, you should be able to in the second fiddle, but you have to be on green div scrolling down OR scroll down after blue and then up.